# Loop over folder of workbooks and export all sheets to tab-delimited text with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I pieced together an Excel VBA script that writes all worksheets in an open workbook to separate, tab-delimited files (is this still a "macro"? I'm learning this in an Excel vacuum). It works well on one workbook at a time. Here it is.

```
Sub exportSheetsToText()
    Dim sWb As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet

    sWb = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".") - 1)

    For Each oSheet In Worksheets
        oSheet.Copy
        sFile = sWb & "-" & oSheet.Name & ".txt"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=sFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next oSheet
End Sub
```

I would like to scale this up so that I can apply this macro to a folder of workbooks. I wrote what I thought would loop over every workbook that satisfies the filter, but it doesn't write any of the .txt files. Here it is.

```
Sub exportsSheetsToTextForAll()

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sWildcard As String
    Dim sMacro As String
    Dim oWb As Workbook
    Dim oPersWb As Workbook

    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Set oPersWb = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB")
    sMacro = "'" & oPersWb.Name & "'" & "!exportSheetsToText()"
    sPath = "C:\Users\richard\Documents\Research\Data\Excel\Datastream - payout"
    sWildcard = "New*.xlsx"
    sFile = Dir(sPath & "\" & sWildcard)


    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=sPath & "\" & sFile
        Application.Run sMacro
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFile = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

It loops through all of my test files, but I don't see any effects (i.e., no .txt files and no errors).

Eventually I will run this on very large workbooks with macros, so it is important to disable the macros (I don't have the macros locally, they're on a dedicated data machine) and close one large workbook before opening the next.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I have just given it a birds view as I have to step out any moment now. Here is one suggestion though... Instead of `Workbooks.Open Filename:=sPath & "\" & sFile` try `Set oWB = Workbooks.Open (Filename:=sPath & "\" & sFile)` and then Also amend your macro to take wb as a parameter so `exportSheetsToText()` becomes `Sub exportSheetsToText(wb as workbook)` Once this is done. Do not work with Activeworkbook in `exportSheetsToText()`. Use `wb` instead.

Comment: are all the files **xlsx** files with extension *.xlsx*

Comment: @Philip - Yes. I made some barebones "New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx" files from the Windows Explorer context menu and populated them with a few columns of `RAND()`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks. I'm working on these suggestions. In general, I'm confused when VBA needs `()`, when it needs `=`, and when it needs `:=`.

Comment: `exportSheetsToText` will always export the files to the current directory, so maybe they're going somewhere other than where you expect to find them? Try adding a `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path` after saving, and see what it produces.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thanks for the `Debug.Print` idea, but it is going to right directory. I think I have a solution - the big problem was @Siddarth's point that I should use the nested `ActiveWorkbook`. Another problem was that my `sMacro` was incorrect. I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

@Siddarth's idea of passing an argument to `exportSheetsToText()` was the key. As well I had an error with macro name passed to `Application.Run`. The following works and is much cleaner.

```
Sub exportsSheetsToTextForAll()

    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    excelFiles = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "New*.xlsx")
    fromPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Do While Len(excelFiles) > 0
        Debug.Print Files
        Set oWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fromPath & "\" & excelFiles)
        Application.Run "exportSheetsToText", oWb
        oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        excelFiles = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Sub exportSheetsToText(iWb As Workbook)

    For Each ws In iWb.Worksheets
        ws.Copy
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        textFile = Left(iWb.FullName, InStr(iWb.FullName, ".") - 1) & "-" & ws.Name & ".txt"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=textFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Bravo! I am happy to see that you have managed to solve it own your own! Sorry couldn't stay and help you as i had to take my mom for a movie :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks! :) Don't worry. I'll back for more help soon. I can't get it to run on the workbook with the macro! I'm not throwing in the towel, yet, though.