# Macro to export worksheets in .xlsx workbooks to tab-delimited .txt files won't work with .xlsm workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Edit: I updated my code based on the comments, but get the same symptoms.

Edit 2: I updated the code, again, and I know that it works on a directory of .xlsx files. If I convert all of the .xlsm files to .xlsx files to drop the macros/code, then the code works great. Likely this problem is too localized.

[Earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975315/loop-over-folder-of-workbooks-and-export-all-sheets-to-tab-delimited-text-with-e/15976556?noredirect=1#comment22780286_15976556) I learned how to loop over a folder of .xlsx files and export every sheet to a tab-delimited .txt file. My bigger goal is to loop over a folder of .xlsm files (whose macros aren't all on my machine) and write the data worksheets to .txt files.

Here's the modified code.

```
Sub exportsSheetsToTextForAll()

    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    excelFiles = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Payout data*.xlsm")
    fromPath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    Do While Len(excelFiles) > 0
        Debug.Print Files
        Set oWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fromPath & "\" & excelFiles)
        Application.Run "exportSheetsToText", oWb
        oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        excelFiles = Dir
    Loop

End Sub

Sub exportSheetsToText(iWb As Workbook)

    For Each ws In iWb.Worksheets
        ws.Copy
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        textFile = Left(iWb.FullName, InStr(iWb.FullName, ".") - 1) & "-" & ws.Name & ".txt"
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=textFile, FileFormat:=xlText
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I modified the answer to my first question due to the structure of the .xlsm files. Each .xlsm file has a data query worksheet ("REQUEST_TABLE") with cells for query entries and buttons for macros. Running the query generates new sheets ("Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc) with the data I want to export.

When I run the `exportAllSheetsToText()` macro it opens the first worksheet, but it starts with the data query worksheet ("REQUEST_TABLE"), saves it to a tab-delimited text file, and stops rather than proceeding through all of the worksheets. I thought that the macro would carry on through all of the sheets as is does with my original macro for looping over all workbooks and worksheets in a directory.

What changes when I run my macro on an .xlsm file? Do I need to strip these worksheets to their own .xlsx files first? Thanks!

Comment: `oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False` You are closing the workbook so how will it loop through the rest of the sheets :)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through/debugging? Can you step through what happens when it copies the first sheet -- in defiance of your `If/Then` logic?  Everything you describe in your expectations seems reasonable and is how I would expect it to work. I don't know of anything that would cause this macro to fail on XLSM files but work when called to run on XLSX files.

Comment: Change oWb to `Activeworkbook` in this `oWb.SaveAs fileName:=sFile, FileFormat:=xlText` and this `oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False`

Comment: Following up on @SiddharthRout comment above you may want to do `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` since the `oWB.Copy` creates a new workbook (which is the ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: @SiddharthRout beat me to it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I made these changes (I think :) ), but I get the same symptoms.

Comment: I still don't understand variable scoping and copying workbooks in VBA. I see `copy` done a lot in examples like this, but I don't know why it's necessary.

Comment: What happens when you debug the section `For Each oSheet In oWb.Worksheets` i.e step through it...

Comment: If I put the breakpoint on the `If Left...`, it says `oSheet.Name` is `Sheet1`, like I want. But it still wants to save the "REQUEST_TABLE".  As I go through it stops just after `SaveAs` and pops up some of the declarations from the target workbook with disabled macros.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Is it possible that, even with macros disabled, when it tries to close the worksheet that the macros in the request sheet throw an error? It is when it moves from `Save` to `Close` that it fails and shows the long list of declarations.

Comment: I just tested the above code (with the suggestions that I made) and it is working just fine for me...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks. I appreciate your help. If I save the .xlsm files to .xlsx (rather than just disable macros) then the macro works great. I guess I need a macro to convert a directory of .xlsm files to .xlsx. :) I am voting to close. I think my problem is too localized and pertains to the macros built into the the data machine and this query .xlsm file. I'll revisit this problem again when I learn more.

Comment: Does the xlsm file with the sheets you want export have code that runs on open, or when specific sheets are activated? If so, you are going to want to start the export code with Application.enableevents = false and set again to true at the end of the procedure.